# Enable camera lens IF in WP8 platform

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a program called [Cam & Weather](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=ddc89efa-36f2-4ad1-9136-9daededc6835) and I am supporting Windows Phone 7.x and Windows Phone 8 platform. This application uses camera. What I'd like to have in the next version is to detect a device if running in Windows Phone 8, so I can register the application for Camera Lens.

I'd like to know how to do this? **IF** the user installed the application in Windows Phone 8, How do you register the application for Camera Lens?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't support Lenses with an app that targets both Windows Phone 7 & Windows Phone 8 with the same XAP.

You will have to upgrade your project to Windows Phone 8 in order to use the new APIs.

If you still want to maitnain a WP7 version of the app, you should look at the options listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206997%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I know it cannot support WP7 because Lenses are only supported in WP8. So I asked if how can I enable such feature (lens) if the user is using WP8 and lens is disabled if a user is using WP7. I'll try to look on your suggested link

Comment: As I said, in order to use Lenses, you'll have to make a **WP8-only** app, so I don't understand why you want to test if the user is using WP7.